# Roslyn -- How to run tests in NamingStylesTests.cs?

Tags: .net, macos, roslyn, xunit.net

I am trying to fix an issue inside Roslyn (https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn), but I am having trouble running some of the unit tests. I am on macOS Ventura with an M2 chip.

Running

```bash
./build.sh --test
```

it runs the tests suite, but it doesn't seem like that e.g. this test runs at all:

```
TestCamelCaseLocalsUpperCaseConstants_ConstLocal
```

the the file in question is

```
src/Analyzers/CSharp/Tests/NamingStyles/NamingStylesTests.cs
```

Can someone help me out?

Comment: You should be able to 'dotnet test' the assembly that contains the tests.

Comment: @JasonMalinowski Could you show me how that is done for this test?

Answer (score 3):

The `Analyzers` layer (i.e, `src/Analyzers` directory) is a shared layer between CodeStyle and Features. This is because Analyzers are shipped in two different ways:

1. With the IDE directly (this comes from Features layer)
2. with the CodeStyle NuGet package (this comes from CodeStyle layer)

So, tests follow the same product structure. The test in question is included in two test assemblies:

1. `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.CodeStyle.UnitTests`
2. `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Features.UnitTests`

So, you can go to `path\to\Roslyn\src\CodeStyle\CSharp\Tests` and run `dotnet test --filter "FullyQualifiedName~NamingStylesTests"`

And to clarify how these tests are being compiled when `src\Analyzers` doesn't have any csproj, the idea is that `src\Analyzers` contains what is so called "shared project", see [CSharpAnalyzers.UnitTests.shproj](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/3226945381c21b8057771851329e7369dac6101a/src/Analyzers/CSharp/Tests/CSharpAnalyzers.UnitTests.shproj) and [CSharpAnalyzers.UnitTests.projitems](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/3226945381c21b8057771851329e7369dac6101a/src/Analyzers/CSharp/Tests/CSharpAnalyzers.UnitTests.projitems).

Then, the shared project is included in [Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Features.UnitTests](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/3226945381c21b8057771851329e7369dac6101a/src/Features/CSharpTest/Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Features.UnitTests.csproj#L51) and [Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.CodeStyle.UnitTests](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/3226945381c21b8057771851329e7369dac6101a/src/CodeStyle/CSharp/Tests/Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.CodeStyle.UnitTests.csproj#L59).

Comment: Thanks a lot! I managed to get one specific test to start now, this is real progress: `dotnet test --filter "FullyQualifiedName~NamingStylesTests.TestPascalCaseMethod_ConstructorsAreIgnored"`. However, it's failing immediately.

Comment: Do you see the same thing on your side? `System.AggregateException : One or more errors occurred. (An exception was thrown while initializing part "Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Test.Utilities.TestExportJoinableTaskContext".) (An exception was thrown while initializing part "Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Test.Utilities.TestExportJoinableTaskContext".)`

Comment: Possibly the same as this? https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/70431

Answer (score 0):

From [Jason Malinowski](https://stackoverflow.com/users/972216/jason-malinowski)'s [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77344024/roslyn-how-to-run-tests-in-namingstylestests-cs#comment136357526_77344024)

> You should be able to '`dotnet test`' the assembly that contains the tests.

To expand on the comment, it should be possible to execute a particular test by first identifying the assembly that contains the test, and then using the `dotnet test` command to run the test.

```bash
[macOS Ventura with M2 chip] ---(build Roslyn)---> [Compiled Roslyn Project]
                                                       |
                                           (dotnet test on specific assembly)
                                                       |
                                                       +--> [Specific Test Assembly]
                                                       |
                                                       +--> [TestCamelCaseLocalsUpperCaseConstants_ConstLocal]
```

Build your [Roslyn](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn) project.

```bash
cd path/to/roslyn
./build.sh
```

Then identify the assembly that contains the `NamingStylesTests.cs`. Usually, the assembly would be the name of the test project, which in this case could be something like `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.UnitTests.dll`. However, this may vary, and you might need to check the project configuration or the build output to find the exact name and location of the assembly.

Once you have identified the assembly, use the `dotnet test` command, specifying the assembly and the `--filter` option, to run the desired test.
See "[Run selected unit tests](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/testing/selective-unit-tests)"

```bash
dotnet test path/to/Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.UnitTests.dll --filter FullyQualifiedName~Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.UnitTests.NamingStylesTests.TestCamelCaseLocalsUpperCaseConstants_ConstLocal
```

With:

- `path/to/Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.UnitTests.dll` the path to the assembly that contains the test.
- `--filter` option, used to specify the fully qualified name of the test to run.

---

> I need some help to actually find the assembly then.
> Here is the full path of my test file: `src/Analyzers/CSharp/Tests/NamingStyles/NamingStylesTests.cs`.
> It doesn't seem like any `.dll` is produced from `./build.sh` that actually contains words like '`Analyzers`' or '`NamingStyles`'.

The project file (`*.csproj`) for the test project should indicate the output assembly name. Navigate to the directory containing `NamingStylesTests.cs`, and look for a `.csproj` file. Open the file and check for an `<AssemblyName>` element.

```bash
cd src/Analyzers/CSharp/Tests/NamingStyles
cat NamingStylesTests.csproj | grep AssemblyName
```

Examine the build output (both on-screen and in any log files) for messages indicating where the assembly is being generated.

```bash
./build.sh | grep -i "NamingStylesTests"
```

Search the build artifacts directory for the assembly. It could be located in a `bin` or `out` directory, possibly under a `Debug` or `Release` subdirectory.

```bash
find . -name '*NamingStylesTests*.dll'
```

It is also possible that the build configuration might be affecting the assembly generation. Make sure the build configuration includes the `NamingStylesTests` project and is configured to generate the assembly.

```bash
cat Build/Targets/Settings.props | grep -i "NamingStylesTests"
```

Comment: Thanks, but I need some help to actually find the assembly then. Here is the full path of my test file: `src/Analyzers/CSharp/Tests/NamingStyles/NamingStylesTests.cs`. It doesn't seem like any .dll is produced from `./build.sh` that actually contains words like 'Analyzers' or 'NamingStyles'.

Comment: @HaraldNordgren I have edited the answer to address your comment.

Comment: Hi again! This folder does not contain a .csproj, same with its direct parent folders: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/tree/main/src/Analyzers/CSharp/Tests/NamingStyles. I found a file Settings.props located at `eng/targets/Settings.props` but again I found no mention of NamingStyle there. Nothing related to `NamingStyle*.dll` is found when I search from the terminal either.

Comment: @HaraldNordgren Is there any result for a `find . -name 'CSharpAnalyzers.UnitTests.dll'`?

Comment: Unfortunately no!

Comment: Check if compiling https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/main/src/Compilers/CSharp/Portable/Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.csproj would trigger the dll creation.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255751/discussion-between-harald-nordgren-and-vonc).

Comment: Hi, did you have another chance to look at this?